# Magento custom product price table

Tags: magento

How to save magento product price in  a custom table rather than catalog_product_enitity_decimal table

Comment: Why do you need this? Magento stores price also in index tables. Maybe you can use that tables?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to save the product price in a custom table, but you can create an observer to listen to the event "catalog_product_save_after". Then you can getFinalPrice() and save it to your custom table.